# CSS display:block not working on google-chrome on windows 7

Tags: google-chrome, css

I am encountering a strange problem in css. You can see the form with checkbox [here](http://mymovierack.com/site/stackoverflow). The text with checkbox is not aligned properly. It splits into two lines. It is working fine on FF, IE, Chromium on Linux and opera but not on chrome on windows 7.
Now here is funny part. Right click any feeling for eg. Must Watch and inspect element.
This is the first matched CSS rule

```
.addCheckbox label, .addRadio label {
font-size: 15px;
}
```

Edit this and add `display:block`.
So the new css will be

```
.addCheckbox label, .addRadio label {
font-size: 15px;
display: block;
}
```

Now disable the newly added CSS by unchecking `display:block` and voila you can see the form perfectly rendered.
So i am getting different rendering with same CSS. Anyone have any clue how to fix this ?
The same CSS was working fine initially with chrome on windows 7 until someone pointed it out recently.

Browser info: Chrome 24.0.1312.57 on Windows 7

Comment: Have you tried to force the display with `.addCheckbox label, .addRadio label { display: inline; }` ?

Comment: By force display u mean adding 'display:block' in my css file ? Yes i have tried it but nothing changed

Comment: Why dont u include the tag <i> which contains icon inside the span of checkbox inline?
Plus remove float:left from checkbox class, I think it is not needed here. And give margin-left to Label. Hope it helps.

Comment: That <i> tag is not making any difference. I have removed them. There is no float:left in checkbox class. Can you point out the line number.

Comment: The class is :
.radio input[type="radio"], .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]
{
float: left;
margin-left: -18px;
}
in out18.css

Comment: @KhurramIshaque thanks that was certainly a move toward right direction. I have updated the code and css but its still showing render problem with radio button.

Comment: well, as far I suggest you is that from this class: .radio.inline, .checkbox.inline... try removing display: inline-block and control the li and span with padding and margin.
For remember me, try using display: block for the Label of Remember me.

Comment: removing display:inline-block or changing it to inline is working perfectly well. You can write your comment as answer and explain the reason so that someone else can benefit from discussion. I will accept  it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove float:left from checkbox class, I think it is not needed here. 
And adjust Label tag with margin-left.

Also, from this class: .radio.inline, .checkbox.inline... try removing display: inline-block and control the li and span with padding and margin. For remember me, try using display: block for the Label of Remember me.

Hope it helps.